# Firefox WebExtension APIs "browser is not defined"

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

ReferenceError: browser is not defined

Cannot find WebExtension APIs on page via console.
In background script all APIs working fine.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs

How to send/receive message via WebExtension APIs on page (Firefox 51).

Comment: I'm sitting here *guessing* at what it is you are attempting to ask, but there are really too many possibilities to explore each of the various ones I'm coming up with as what you might mean. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that print a notification when you click on the button (it works for me).

Do not forget to declare the permissions for your needs in the manifest.

**Disclaimer**: it seems that Firefox throw an error for browser variable, but it works.

---

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "webextension-example",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "An example.",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

---

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="pony">Notify</button>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### script.js

```
window.addEventListener("click", notifyExtension)
function notifyExtension(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'pony') {
        return
    }
    browser.runtime.sendMessage('FooBar')
}
```

---

#### background.js

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify)
function notify(message) {
    browser.notifications.create({
        "type": "basic",
        "title": "You clicked a link!",
        "message": message
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I`ve been doing migrate extension from chrom to firefox.
In content script I`ve tried get browser APIs via window namespace (like in chrome), to not to produce ReferenceError, if something went wrong.

But in firefox, browser APIs available only for content script.

Comment: Note that [because of a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208775), `window.browser` isn't always there. If you're getting this error in a content script, try `this.browser` in global scope.